# Put constraint on PhoenixFramework changeset

Tags: phoenix-framework

I have three models in Phoenix Framework, `User`, `Post`, `Vote`. **Users can down vote the post only when they have more than 1 point**. The user point is calculated by the up votes their posts got from other users.

This is what I defined in my `Vote` model:

```
  schema "votes" do
    field :type, :integer # -1 0 1
    belongs_to :user, News.User
    belongs_to :post, News.Post

    timestamps()
  end
```

Because the user points is not defined in `Vote` schema, so I can't use `validate_change` or `add_error` directly in model, unless I read other models' data to decide whether to add error to changeset, obviously it will be doing too many things in `Vote` model.

Where should I put the constraint? Controller or model?

Maybe I should place constraint on the database, make sure the user point never get below zero? I found something like trigger. But how will [PostgreSQL trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createtrigger.html) return their result to the changeset?

### Updated (this one works, but I'm not sure if it's the best way)

I tried it in my controller:

```
def create(conn, %{"vote" => vote_params}, user) do
    changeset = user
      |> build_assoc(:votes)
      |> Vote.changeset(vote_params)

    changeset = if user.point < 1 do
      Ecto.Changeset.add_error(changeset, :user_id, "You points is not enough.")
    end

    case Repo.insert(changeset) do
      {:ok, vote} ->
        conn
        |> put_status(:created)
        |> put_resp_header("location", vote_path(conn, :show, vote))
        |> render("show.json", vote: vote)
      {:error, changeset} ->
        conn
        |> put_status(:unprocessable_entity)
        |> render(WechatNews.ChangesetView, "error.json", changeset: changeset)
    end
  end
```

It's easy, but I have to repeat it in the `update` action too.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something along the lines of

```
def changeset(struct, params) do
  struct
  |> cast([:points], params)
  |> validate_required(:points)
end

def point_changeset(struct, params) do
  struct
  |> changeset(params)
  |> check_points
end

defp check_points(changeset) do
  if get_field(changeset, :points) < 1 do
    add_error(changeset, :points, "too low")
  else
    changeset
  end
end
```

This would give you a function `point_changeset/2`, which you can use only when you need to check that a user can do a certain action based on their points. It still calls the main `changeset/2` function that has your validations that you want to always run.

Comment: I just took the code you had and put it in a changeset function so it can be validated. I don't know the internals of your application. You will need to place this where it makes sense.

Comment: The `points` is not defined in `Vote` schema. The `Vote` schema only has `type`, `post_id` and `user_id`. So I can't get its value directly from changeset, I must compute it with all up votes user got and the down votes they made.

Comment: That isn't really the point of my answer. I gave you an idea of how you can do this within a changeset so that you do not need to duplicate the logic, but you would still have the validation whenever you wanted to use it. instead of the `get_field/2` call, you are going to have to do your calculation to know how many points are available...